# How to implement std::ops::Index when the output value is not part of the type

Tags: rust, operator-overloading, lifetime, traits

I am trying to implement an ip address type that basically wraps `u32`:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Hash)]
pub struct Address(u32);
```

I'm implementing the `std::ops` operators that makes sense for an IP address (`&`, `|`, `+`, `-`, etc.). The only one that is causing trouble is `std::ops::Index`:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Hash)]
pub struct Address(u32);

enum Byte {
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D
}

impl ops::Index<Byte> for Address {
    type Output = u8;

    fn index<'a>(&'a self, byte: Byte) -> &'a Self::Output {
        match byte {
            Byte::A => ((self.0 & 0xFF000000) >> 24) as u8,
            Byte::B => ((self.0 & 0x00FF0000) >> 16) as u8,
            Byte::C => ((self.0 & 0x0000FF00) >> 8) as u8,
            Byte::D => (self.0 & 0x000000FF) as u8,
        }
    }
}
```

This obviously does not compile because I cannot return an `u8` when `&u8` is expected. The naive attempt to fix it would be:

```
impl ops::Index<Byte> for Address {
    type Output = u8;

    fn index<'a>(&'a self, byte: Byte) -> &'a Self::Output {
        match byte {
            Byte::A => &(((self.0 & 0xFF000000) >> 24) as u8),
            Byte::B => &(((self.0 & 0x00FF0000) >> 16) as u8),
            Byte::C => &(((self.0 & 0x0000FF00) >> 8) as u8),
            Byte::D => &((self.0 & 0x000000FF) as u8),
        }
    }
}
```

But of course, I cannot return a reference to a value that does not exist anymore once the function returns.

I there a way to implement `std::ops::Index` in this case? It does not seem so to me, but I hope someone can prove me wrong.

Comment: At the risk of missing something obvious, there is already a [`Ipv4Addr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.Ipv4Addr.html) that wraps the appropriate underlying type.

Comment: @Shepmaster, yes but I'd like to use this in a traffic generation tool, so I want (at least) the `+`, `&`, `<<` and `>>` operators implemented. Afaik I cannot implement this easily on `Ipv4Addr` because I don't have a direct access to the underlying type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the simplest and most idiomatic way to solve this is to *not* implement `Index`, and instead just use a method called `octet` or something.  `Index` is for indexing into containers; it simply isn't compatible with generating new values on the fly.

So.  There's your answer.

---

You absolutely should *not* do anything I'm *about* to describe, because there is no good reason to do it, and I'm only writing it out because you *technically* asked if there was any way at all...

You've been warned.

... The octets are *right there*!  Unless you're compiling for a machine with bytes that *aren't* 8 bits, or has more granular addressing than 8 bits, there's no reason you can't just do this:

```
use std::ops;

#[derive(Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Hash)]
pub struct Address(u32);

enum Byte {
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D
}

impl ops::Index<Byte> for Address {
    type Output = u8;

    #[cfg(target_endian="big")]
    fn index<'a>(&'a self, byte: Byte) -> &'a u8 {
        use std::mem;
        let bytes = unsafe { mem::transmute::<_, &[u8; 4]>(&self.0) };
        match byte {
            Byte::A => &bytes[0],
            Byte::B => &bytes[1],
            Byte::C => &bytes[2],
            Byte::D => &bytes[3],
        }
    }

    #[cfg(target_endian="little")]
    fn index<'a>(&'a self, byte: Byte) -> &'a u8 {
        use std::mem;
        let bytes = unsafe { mem::transmute::<_, &[u8; 4]>(&self.0) };
        match byte {
            Byte::A => &bytes[3],
            Byte::B => &bytes[2],
            Byte::C => &bytes[1],
            Byte::D => &bytes[0],
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(Address(0x12345678)[Byte::A], 0x12);
}
```

I mean, aside from this being a needless use of `unsafe` for the sake of confusing syntax; indexing an *address* makes about as much sense as indexing an integer: very little.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining _why_ it's a wrong thing to do, and answering the question anyway. I'm not implementing `Index`, I promise!